# What does 'return this' do when augmenting types?

Tags: javascript

Crockford's book JavaScript the Good Parts talks about a function for augmenting basic types. His function looks like this:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}
```

I don't understand how / why the 'this' variable is used here. I've only used 'this' when calling that function with 'new', but this function is instead called like this:

```
Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this)
});
```

Comment: it allows for object call chaining: `foo->bar()->baz()`.

Comment: By the way, marking this as duplicate of that question is incorrect. I know what 'return this' normally does in a function, thats simple. My confusion is only of how it works in this specific situation. People on SO have like Quick Draw syndrome to close things and mark duplicate, fastest trigger fingers in the wild west. At least think more carefully before marking duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the *Object* which the function was referenced though when invoked.

```
var obj = {fn: function() {return this;}};
obj.fn(); // obj

var fn = obj.fn;
fn(); // window or null or error

fn.call(obj); // obj
fn.apply(obj); // obj
```

*method* is on `Function.prototype`, this means all *Function* instances inherit *method* and `this` inside `method` is expected to refer to the function instance which you're invoking it though, i.e.

```
Function.prototype.getThis = function () {return this;};
function hello() {}
hello.getThis(); // hello
// and consequently
hello.getThis().getThis().getThis().getThis().getThis(); // hello
```

*Constructors* are *Functions* too. Therefore all *constructors* inherit the *method*. The *method* example here hence means *"Add a property `name` to the prototype inherited by instances of `this` (the constructor) and set the value of that property to `func`, then return the constructor so you can chain it"*

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.method('bar', 'baz').method('fizz', 'buzz'); // Foo

var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar; // "baz", inherited from Foo.prototype
foo.fizz; // "buzz", inherited from Foo.prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to its execution context. More precisely, *it's used inside a function, and refers to the object that invoked it*.